# How to add html elements to a string and display them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following string, `Today is a beautiful day` and a substring with a `start`: `3` and `end`: `20` properties index to form `ay is a beautiful` . note the whitespace in the substring.

What I'm trying to accomplish is render the string **dynamically** with its substring in bold, like this:

Tod**ay is a beautiful** day

Which I'm imagining would go somewhat like what I've tried, by manipulating the string and adding `<b>` in it: `Tod<b>ay is a beautiful </b> day`, which will only return a string showing the `<b>`

I also tried returning an html element with the string between tags: `<h1> Tod{bold sentence}day </h1>` which makes it too complicated to merge a separated word and, manage whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `useMemo` function to generate such a jsx structure:

```js
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Today is a beautiful day");
  const [[start, end], setRange] = useState([3, 20]);

  const paragraph = useMemo(() => (
    <p>
      <span>{text.substring(0, start)}</span>
      <strong>{text.substring(start, end + 1)}</strong>
      <span>{text.substring(end + 1)}</span>
    </p>
  ),[text, start, end]);

  return (
    <div className="App">{paragraph}</div>
  );
}
```

Check the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-leaf-2hmnv?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: OP wants strong upto endIndex, So I guess it should be `str.substring(start, end + 1);`

Comment: @SAM You're right, thanks for pointing out. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
const str = "Today is a beautiful day";

function makeStrongDynamically(str, start, end) {
  const res = str
    .split("")
    .map((s, i) => {
      if (i === start) return `<b>${s}`;
      else if (i === end) return `${s}</b>`;
      else return s;
    })
    .join("");
  return res;
}

const innerHTML = makeStrongDynamically(str, 3, 20);
const element = document.querySelector(".str-attached");
element.innerHTML = innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="str-attached"></div>
```

Using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
const str = "Today is a beautiful day";

function makeStrongDynamically(str, start, end) {
  const before = str.substring(0, start);
  const center = str.substring(start, end + 1);
  const after = str.substring(end + 1);

  return `${before}<b>${center}</b>${after}`;
}

const innerHTML = makeStrongDynamically(str, 3, 20);
const element = document.querySelector(".str-attached");
element.innerHTML = innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="str-attached"></div>
```

Comment: how to render this in React? without document.querySelector

Comment: you could use `useRef`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I have done this in javascript.

```js
const startIndex = 3;
const endIndex = 20;
const myString = 'Today is a beautiful day';

const mySubString = myString.substring(3, 20);
const startString = myString.substring(0, startIndex);
const endString = myString.substring(endIndex, myString.length)



console.log(startString + "<strong>" + mySubString + "</strong>" + endString);
```

if you want to render in reactjs then use below.

```
{`${startString}<strong>${mySubString}</strong>${endString}`}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add do this conditionally, given that I have a 'start' and 'end' substring, and not manually.

Comment: Oh okay let me edit my answer then. Give me sometime.

Comment: OP wants strong upto endIndex, So I guess it should be `str.substring(start, end + 1);`